# how to save comment give by user and and how to save that in webserver database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend i have to make comment page for user as well as me too
for eg i have map and on that map i select some place and i look some good picture and i taken that picture afterword i have shared that picture as public for comment on that picture if the user comment on that picture then it should be come on review for me how much comment given by user on my picture and and i have to store also in local database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it any details in `NSDictionary` which will enable you to have different details stored and all of them can be accessed by using the unique `Key`. If you have multiple elements its better if u maintain an array of dictionaries with each element in the array represent an unique entity and the details of that particular entity is available in the dictionary